# disable last column sorting in datatable js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Guys I am using below given API for table display and do't want to sort last column .
https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js

Comment: `{"bSort": false}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
columnDefs: [{
  targets: -1,
  orderable: false
}]
```

`targets: -1` points to the last column.

See **https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable**